# Finding $m+n$ from $m+n+mn+1=91$

Tags: diophantine-equations

If $m,n$ are natural numbers such that $m+n+mn+1=91$ .Then how to find $m+n$

Comment: Are you aware that there's actually multiple solutions to the equation and hence multiple values $m+n$ can be?

Comment: @Noble First half is true, second half is false (unless you include $0$ in the natural numbers).

Comment: @ErickWong Ah right, I was actually including $0 \in \mathbb{N}$ which is the convention my course takes.

Comment: @DonAntonio-correct, as for (m+1)(n+1)=mn+m+n+1=91,m+1=7 and n+1=13 or vice versa,because (6*12)+6+12+1=(12*6)+12+6+1=91,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$mn+m+n+1=91\Longrightarrow m(n+1)+(n+1)=91\Longrightarrow (m+1)(n+1)=91$$

But $\,91=7\cdot 13\,$ , so...

Answer (score 4):

**Hint**: $$m+n+mn+1=(m+1)(n+1).$$